# Using ASP.NET Identity 2.0 in web forms project

Tags: webforms, asp.net-identity

I'm upgrading user management pages of my old web forms project to use new Identity 2.0. This means introducing MVC pages within web forms solution but so far it does not seem to be a big issue. Most of the functionality works fine except when I'm trying to add external auth provider (Google, FCBK) to already signed in user. I'm working off Identity 2.0 sample app and my problem happens in equivalent of /manage/linklogin action within Identity 2.0 sample app.

In here, external auth provider (let's say Google) should be challenged by setting HTTP 401 into current response, resulting in a browser redirect:

```
Location: https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud?openid.ns=[edited out...]
```

However, what happens to me is that I only get redirected to a local login page:

```
Location: /Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fManageAccount%2fLinkLogin
```

Please note that the very same code is called when I try to ***register*** (i.e. user is not logged in, not authenticated) using Google account - so it is **not** an issue that I'd have `app.UseGoogleAuthentication()` set wrongly in Startup.Auth.cs.

I suspect "something" in the response pipeline catches StatusCode 401 set by Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationManager.Challenge() method before Owin.Security.Google auth middleware kicks in and set the proper redirect location, though I cannot find what that "something" is.

Anyone successfully imported Identity 2.0 into web forms project already?

More info on my issue can be found here: [Identity2.0 Codeplex discussion](http://aspnetidentity.codeplex.com/discussions/541044)

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this sample for ASP.NET Web Forms which shows the Identity 2.0 features https://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/Identity/Webforms.Samples/

You should also make sure the order of registering the middlewares is correct. For eg. Cookies should come before Google

Comment: Pranav - all my code settings is exactly in the same order as in sample apps. The only difference I see is the User property of HttpContext (and lately OwinContext) - while in sample apps, User is type of System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal, in my app User is System.Web.Security.RolePrincipal. I've removed all Forms Auth related code from my web.config but still cannot find where the type for User object is being set.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah this was a challenge. You are correct in your observation of it's
 behavior. The config info below resolved this issue for me. 
The very bottom config tag that excludes the callback path caused 
it to start functioning as expected for me.

```
 <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication"/>
    </modules>    
  </system.webServer>


  <system.web>


    <authentication mode="None"/>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>

  <location path="login.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>

<!-- the callback path has to be open to anonymous so that owin can do it's redirect magic-->
  <location path="signin-google">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```